# AVAudioRecorder fails recording when the directory is changed

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, avaudiorecorder

I'm recording some audio and it was OK when i was using this code to select the directory the audio data was being stored:

```
NSArray *folders = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                           NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsFolder = [folders objectAtIndex:0];
result = [documentsFolder stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Recording.m4a"];
```

But i need to store the audio files in another directory, then i tried this code:

```
NSArray *folders = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                           NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsFolder = [folders objectAtIndex:0];
result = [documentsFolder stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Sounds/Recording.m4a"];
```

The AVAudioRecorder instance is initialized with the new path, but when i call `[myAudioRecorer prepareToRecord]` and `[myAudioRecorder record]` it fails and any sound is recorded.

How can i change the directory correctly?

PS: i also tried to create a new directory with NSFileManager, but it didn't work. I was doing this way:

```
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:pathAsString withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:&error]
```

EDITED:

here is the code where i record the audio:

```
//here is the method that returns the path i want to save the files    
- (NSString *) audioRecordingPath{ 
        NSString *result = nil;
        NSArray *folders = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                           NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsFolder = [folders objectAtIndex:0];
        result = [documentsFolder stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Sounds/Recording.m4a"];
        return result;
    }

//just the record settings
    - (NSDictionary *) audioRecordingSettings{ 
        NSDictionary *result = nil;

        NSMutableDictionary *settings = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        [settings setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:kAudioFormatAppleLossless] forKey:AVFormatIDKey];
        [settings setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:44100.0f] forKey:AVSampleRateKey];

        [settings setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:1] forKey:AVNumberOfChannelsKey];
        [settings setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:AVAudioQualityLow] forKey:AVEncoderAudioQualityKey];
        result = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:settings];
        return result; 

    }

//here is where i record the audio
    - (IBAction)recordAudio{

        NSError *error = nil;

        NSString *pathAsString = [self audioRecordingPath];

        NSURL *audioRecordingURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:pathAsString];
        self.audioRecorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:audioRecordingURL settings:[self audioRecordingSettings] error:&error];

        if (self.audioRecorder != nil){
            self.audioRecorder.delegate = self;
            if ([self.audioRecorder prepareToRecord] && [self.audioRecorder record]){ 
                NSLog(@"Successfully started to record.");

            } else {
                NSLog(@"Failed to record.");// the error returned.
                self.audioRecorder = nil; 
            }
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Failed to create an instance of the audio recorder.");
        } 

    }
```

Comment: Did you try using `stringByAppendingPathComponent` twice?

Comment: Show your code for creating the directory and then adding a file to it.

Comment: Put the document creation code in your file somewhere where it will only be executed once. Change your audiorecordingpath method accordingly and see if that works